# async/await concurrent function calls in javascript (Chain functions)

Tags: javascript, async-await

I think I'm probably misunderstanding how to use async/await, but I'm struggling to find a solution that doesn't dive into promises.

I have an if statement that contains two functions.  I need functionTwo to run only after functionOne has completed.  adding async and await before them doesn't seem to work, but I don't think I'm a million miles away.

Any help would be great!  Thank you!

```
if (someBoolean) {
  functionOne();
  functionTwo();
}

if (someBoolean) {
  async functionOne();
  await functionTwo();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `await` for both.

```
if (someBoolean) {
  await functionOne();
  await functionTwo();
}
```

`async` is used when you declare the functions

```
async function functionOne() {... }
```

Comment: Currently getting an error - `Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function`.  That might be related to my app?

Comment: @Nick You have to declare the function that this `if` statement is inside as async. e.g- `function func() { if(someBoolen) { await func1; await func2; } }`. The `async` keyword basiclly says `this function is going to have some async operation inside`, and then the `await` comes before that async operation and waits for it to finish before it continues the async function.

Answer (score 0):

async/await uses Promises! So I think that's not the best way to go if you want to avoid Promises. Your best bet might be to include a callback in your first function.

```js
function one(callback) {
  /* do your stuff here */
  if (typeof callback === 'function) {
    callback()
  }
}

function two() {/* do the second set of things here */}

if (someBoolean) {
  one(two)
}
```